# Spring Boot: Apparent connection leak detected

Tags: spring-boot

### I want to delete old records in batch job tables.

But there is always an error `Apparent connection leak detected` .

I tried to increase `leak-detection-threshold` to 10minutes and it didn't help.
But if I remove the lines associated with `query.executeUpdate` it works.
It is also necessary to output how many rows were affected.

My code:

```
 @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Scheduled(cron = "${schedule.clearing-job-tables}")
  @Transactional
  public void clearJobTables() {
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
      "DELETE FROM batch_step_execution_context WHERE step_execution_id IN (SELECT batch_step_execution.step_execution_id FROM batch_step_execution WHERE job_execution_id IN (SELECT job_execution_id FROM batch_job_execution WHERE create_time < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days' ));\n" +
        "DELETE FROM batch_step_execution WHERE job_execution_id IN (SELECT job_execution_id FROM batch_job_execution WHERE create_time < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days' );\n" +
        "DELETE FROM batch_job_execution_context WHERE job_execution_id IN (SELECT job_execution_id FROM batch_job_execution WHERE create_time < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days' );\n" +
        "DELETE FROM batch_job_execution_params WHERE job_execution_id IN (SELECT job_execution_id FROM batch_job_execution WHERE create_time < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days' );\n" +
        "DELETE FROM batch_job_execution WHERE job_execution_id NOT IN(SELECT job_execution_id FROM batch_step_execution) AND create_time < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days' ;\n" +
        "DELETE FROM batch_job_instance WHERE job_instance_id NOT IN (SELECT job_instance_id FROM batch_job_execution);"
    );
    if (query.executeUpdate() > 0) {
      System.out.println("Cleared records in Batch job tables: " + query.executeUpdate());
    } else
      System.out.println("Nothing was deleted from Batch job tables");
  }
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:108)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:138)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:276)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:284)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:164)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:421)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy146.getTransaction(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:595)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:382)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
at team.alabs.bcc.ocrm.channel.config.batch.BatchScheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6199c95f.clearJobTables(<generated>)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of trying, I decided to use another method and found [this](https://github.com/arey/spring-batch-toolkit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/javaetmoi/core/batch/tasklet/RemoveSpringBatchHistoryTasklet.java)!
Edited the method under *@Scheduled*. And it works!
[Deleted rows result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcTGL.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).